# Parallels 16 , Ubuntu22 tools install fails

Tags: 22.04, parallels

trying to install parallels tools into a clean Ubuntu 22.04 VM with Parallels 16. The install fails immediately with

Error: Xorg version 1.21 not supported

Obviously a version conflict. Parallels is up to date, does not show there is a pending update other the pay update to P17. Anyone knows of a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 22.04 uses Wayland rather than Xorg for its display protocol, which requires Parallels 17.1 or newer. If you're not keen on upgrading Parallels but need Ubuntu 22.04 specifically, you can try one of the flavours, such as Xubuntu or Ubuntu MATE.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just tried Xubuntu22 / Lubuntu22 with the same outcome...